# Why is is there no value when there a text in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, backbone.js, slim

I created a table of users using mysql using this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `department` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `tel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `role` text NOT NULL,
 `other` text NOT NULL,
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `department` (`department`)
);
```

then I use this php code in the Slim framework to create some RESTful api:

```
// GET all users route
$app->get('/users', function () {

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name';

  try {
  $db = getConnection();
  $stmt = $db->query($sql);
  $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $db = null;

  echo '{"users":' . json_encode($users) . '}';

  } catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
    echo '{"error": { text: ' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
  }
});
```

in **Backnone**

```
define([
'underscore', 
'backbone'
], 
function(_, Backbone) {

  return Backbone.Model.extend({

    //urlRoot: 'scripts/data/users',

    defaults: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'anon',
        department: 'Agency Anon',
        tel: '0207 123 45 67',
        email: 'anon@sample.com',
        date: '1 January 2014',
        role: 'Snr Developer',
        other: 'Lorem ipsum',
        status: 0
    }
  });
});
```

All these work as expected, i.e. all fields are returning the excepted results, except the `role` and `other` fields who are returning a null value in the firebug console.

**The result I get** (notice `role` and `other`, they should be text, not `null`:

```
{
  "users":[{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Sabrina Materoli",
    "department":"Marketing",
    "tel":"0207 000 1110",
    "email":"sabrina@company.com",
    "date":"2014-06-12 11:43:43",
    "role":null,
    "other":null,
    "status":"0"
  }]
}
```

Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this(`echo '{"users":' . json_encode($users) . '}';`) display correctly?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct json except for `role` and `other` which have null as value instead of a text. And I'm sure I've entered some text in the database.

Comment: Let's try this and what it shows? `$users = $stmt->fetchAll(); print_r($users);`

Comment: It shows an array with all the data I need plus the json. But the json is still the same with `null` set on role and other.

Comment: Now remove this one.`echo '{"users":' . json_encode($users) . '}';`, and behalf of that add this `$new_users['users'] = $users; echo json_encode($new_users);`

Comment: I still get null... I think it's something to do with the sql data types or attributes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Shaoz What is the actual value in the database for the two fields for Sabrina?

Comment: @Shaoz : Nope. I think no problem in datatypes. Show of your two field values

Comment: the values of `role`: `Front-end Developer @ senior level` and `other`: `At Apple (in UK), owns a macbook pro`.

Comment: Set your fields with normal string and check.(means remove special chars)

Comment: Yep, it works now. So the special chars were problem. For the moment they're set to `latin1_swedish_ci`, so how can I set the fields to accept specials chars? Please, place your answer into the answer box, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion, I found the solution for your bug.

The problem occurs only for `special characters` mixed with your text field . like `@`, `$`...

Try to use `utf8_general_ci` for your DB collation.